# "Replace expected at least 2 arguments" - trying to write script for hangman game, need to replace letters with underscores

Tags: python, str-replace

I need to replace the characters of a word with underscores for a hangman game. For example, "apple" would become "_ _ _ _ _". This is my code:

```
import random

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

for letter in chosen_word:
  str.replace(letter, "_ ")
```

The error message I'm receiving is

> "File "main.py", line 17, in

> str.replace(letter, "_")

> TypeError: replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

As far as I can tell, there *are* two arguments. I've tried messing around with format and the arguments (letter, "_ "), but to be honest, I'm a total noob and have no idea what went wrong.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `str.replace()`, there is no string named `str` in your code.

```
import random

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

for letter in chosen_word:
  chosen_word = chosen_word.replace(letter, "_ ")
```

Also, in your case this might be simpler:

```
new_word = ''
for letter in chosen_word:
    new_word += '_ '
```